# KeePass: All passwords encrypted/encoded

Tags: keepass

Last week all my passwords in my KeePass database got changed. The amount of characters is unchanged as far as I can see it. So I guessing they are somehow encoded or encrypted.

The only thing I can think of is that I was connecting IntelliJ with the password database. Maybe it did change something during import.

I have a backup of the database, but I would lose a lot of passwords.

Has anyone ideas what I can do?

Comment: Without knowing what happened, I don't know if we can help you. If you can give a more exact description of what happened we may be able to help.

Comment: Sorry, I've really have no idea. At some point all passwords were changed. I really just hoped someone has seen it or experienced it by himself.

Comment: Then all we can do is guess, sadly. Without knowing the reason for the change, it is unlikely we'll be able to find a solution. You should check for any logs that may record changes to KeePass or for system events around the time the change occurred. If you think IntelliJ is to blame, then you should have an idea what happened, and more information about that could help.

Comment: Thanks. I know my question is not ideal. I was grasping at straws. I really just configured my database file in IntelliJ, so IntelliJ can store my GERRIT password inside of it. I did not see anything in the logs. However, the strange thing is even I can't use the passwords in the database anymore the stored GERRIT password is still usable by IntelliJ. But when I look into the database, the password is not readable by me. However, I opened a ticket within the IntelliJ issue tracker. Maybe they can help me out or help me understand what happened.